# Programmatic access to a heading's todo state changes

Tags: org-mode

Is there a mechanism in org-mode to programmatically extract all TODO keyword/state change information from a heading?  For example with the following:

```
* DONE Test
- State "DONE"       from "CANCELED"       [2017-10-20 Fri 15:50]
- State "CANCELED"   from "WAIT"       [2017-10-20 Fri 15:33]
- State "WAIT"       from "TODO"       [2017-10-20 Fri 15:14] \\
  Foo
  bar
  baz
- State "TODO"       from "WAIT"       [2017-10-20 Fri 15:14]
- State "WAIT"       from "TODO"       [2017-10-20 Fri 15:11] \\
  Waiting for something
```

Obtain a list of alists/plists- each with the old-state, new-state, timestamp string, and the possibly multiline note.  If not- what would be a robust approach to do so?

Some observations:

1. A close relation to these state changes are clocking entries, but they follow a different structure.  Are there other similar such entries used elsewhere in org-mode?
2. State entries may be intermixed with clock entries- at least.
3. There is commonly variation in indentation.
4. State and clock entries may optionally be constrained to drawers (per the `org-log-into-drawer` and `org-clock-into-drawer` values).
5. A drawer is probably necessary to unambiguously extract a final note value.

If the format is used by org-mode for encoding other types of information a more generalized solution would be fine.